# Show that $ \lim_{x\to 0} \left( \cos(\sin(x)) + \tfrac12x^2\right)^ {\left[(e^{x^2}-1)\left(1+2x-\sqrt{1+4x+2x^2} \right)\right]^{-1}} = e^{5/24}$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

I can't find following limit:

$$ \lim_{x\to 0} \left( \cos(\sin(x)) + \tfrac12x^2\right)^
{\frac{1}{(e^{x^2}-1)\left(1+2x-\sqrt{1+4x+2x^2} \right)}} = e^{5/24}$$

I've tried l'hospital's rule, and everything else i know but i does't seem to work.I have solution but i need all steps.
I would appreciate it if someone could help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you show us some of what you've done, so that we can better help you?

Comment: Well there isn't much to show, tried l'hospital and got stuck after few derivatives, tried using lim(1+x)^1/x as x->0 rule, got stuck again, so i don't have any work to show as i believe my methods are wrong

Comment: It looks pretty horrible, but there seems to be no reason why it wouldn't work to take the logarithm first and then develop numerator and denominator of $$ \frac{\log\left( \cos(\sin(x)) + \tfrac12x^2\right) } {\bigl(e^{x^2}-1\bigr)\bigl( 1+2x-\sqrt{1+4x+2x^2} \bigr)} $$ in powers of $x$ to a sufficiently high degree. It looks like the numerator ought to have a nonzero coefficient for $x^4$, so that should be enough.

Comment: I am sorry i just started learning calculus, and i can't follow you, i am not really sure what you did there

Comment: @MathewSigurdson: I took the logarithm of the big complicated power, using the rule $\log(a^b) = \log(a)\cdot b$. That gives the fraction above. If you haven't learned about power series, then applying L'Hospital's rule four times in succession to the fraction ought to give a finite limit -- but that way is probably going to cost you a ridiculous amount of paper ...

Comment: Hmm i better learn that, because i don't think i have time on exam for L'Hospital's rule

Comment: Denominator in @HenningMakholm rewriting is of order $4$, so you would need L'Hospital 4 times (which is ugly). Consider Maclaurin's expansion instead.

Comment: Indeed, this is such an ugly problem that my recommendation might be to get a new teacher. :) When Henning can't come up with a quick way to do a calc problem, it's probably just tougher than one could reasonably expect students to handle.

Comment: Maclaurin's expansion of the numerator https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+ln(cos(sin(x))%2Bx%5E2%2F2) The first coefficient looks right.

Comment: @JohnHughes: I strongly suspect the material the OP is supposed to have learned does include series expansion to a finite degree. If one knows how to manipulate such series (ending with an $o(x^n)$), then this one is not quite as horrible as it looks -- and actually would seem to be a reasonable exercise in such manipulations.

Comment: Since he said "I'm sorry, I just started learning calculus...", I suspect he has *not* encountered such things. Otherwise, I agree with you completely.

Comment: I've never seen this in my life, trying to learn it know, but as i see it is also taking bunch of derivatives to get approximation of function, how will that be better than L'Hospital's rule ?

Comment: The problem is easily solved if we note that $$\cos(\sin x) + \frac{x^{2}}{2} - 1 = \frac{x^{2} - 4\sin^{2}((\sin x)/2)}{2} = \frac{\{x - 2\sin((\sin x)/2)\}\{x + 2\sin((\sin x)/2)\}}{2}$$ However you need to use L'Hospital's once to get the final answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really difficult, but somewhat lengthy if you use *equivalents* and remember you can *compose* Taylor's polynomials. It all amounts to finding the limit of the logarithm of the expression:
$$\ln\Bigl(\cos(\sin x)+\frac{x^2}2\Bigl)^{\tfrac 1{(\mathrm e^{x^2}-1)(1+2x-\sqrt{1+4x+2x^2})}}=\frac{\ln\Bigl(\cos(\sin x)+\frac{x^2}2\Bigl)} {(\mathrm e^{x^2}-1)(1+2x-\sqrt{1+4x+2x^2})}.$$

Let's expand the numerator at order $4$:

- $\displaystyle\sin x=x-\frac{x^3}6+o(x^4)$ and $\cos u=1-\dfrac{u^2}2+\dfrac{u^4}{24}+o(u^4)$, so
  \begin{align*}\cos(\sin x)+\frac{x^2}2&=1-\frac12\Bigl(x-\frac{x^3}6\Bigr)^2+\frac1{24}\Bigl(x-\frac{x^3}6\Bigr)^4+o(x^4)+\frac{x^2}2\\
  &=1+\frac{x^4}6+\frac{x^4}{24}+o(x^4)=1+\frac{5x^4}{24}+o(x^4)
  \end{align*}
- $\ln(1+u)=u+o(u)$, so
  $$\ln\Bigl(\cos(\sin x)+\frac{x^2}2\Bigl)=\ln\Bigl(1+\frac{5x^4}{24}+o(x^4)\Bigl)=\frac{5x^4}{24}+o(x^4)\sim_0 \frac{5x^4}{24}$$
  Similarly for the denominator. It's enough to expand each factor at order $2$:
- $\mathrm e^{x^2}-1=x^2+o(x^2)\sim_0 x^2$.
- $\sqrt{1+u}=1+\dfrac{u}2-\dfrac{u^2}8+o(u^2)$
- $\begin{aligned}[t]1+2x-\sqrt{1+4x+2x^2}&= 1+2x-1-\frac12(4x+2x^2)+\frac18(4x+2x^2)^2+o(x^2)\\
  &= -x^2+\frac{16x^2}8+o(x^2)=x^2+o(x^2)\sim_0 x^2
  \end{aligned}$

Thus the logarithm of the expression is equivalent to $\;\dfrac{\,\dfrac{5x^4}{24}\,}{x^4}=\dfrac{5}{24}$, whence the limit.